# Get data for referenced object

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, reference

I have a Recipe Model and FoodComponent Model which belongsTo Recipe.

RecipeModel :

```
class Recipe extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'recipes';

    protected $fillable = [ 
        'details'
    ];

    public function foods(){
            return $this->hasMany('App\FoodComponent','id','food_id');
    }
}
```

FoodComponent model:

```
class FoodComponent extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'food_components';

    protected $fillable = [ 'title',
        'menu_id',
        'image'
    ];

    public function recipes(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Recipe','id','food_id');
    }
}
```

RecipeController:

```
public function index()
    {  
        $recipes = Recipe::all();

        return view('recipes.index')->with('recipes',$recipes);
    }
```

And in the view I have

```
@foreach($recipes as $recipe)
       {{ $recipe->foods }}
 @endforeach
```

I get something like this :

```
[{"id":1,"menu_id":1,"title":"Pollo Locco","image":"images\/uploads\/foodcomponents\/99254.jpg","created_at":"2016-08-12 10:01:38","updated_at":"2016-08-12 10:01:38"}]
```

But I want just the 'title'.

I've tried with $recipe->foods->title. But is not working.

Can you give me an idea how can I display just the title please ?

Thank you !

Comment: try this $recipe->foods[0]->title. let me know if this works.

Comment: It worked! Thank you!

Comment: Great to hear but this will work only on a single record. You can create a counter or use the answer provided by @linuxartisan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
@foreach($recipes as $recipe)
  @foreach($recipe->foods as $food)
   {{ $food->title }}
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```